# What supplies can only be found in plane-drops?

Tags: rust

Some supplies can never be found in random crates, only crates dropped by planes.  Which supplies are these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 **Survival**
    Low Quality Metal
    Metal Door

**Resource**
    Gunpowder
    Wood Planks

**Medical**
    Large Medkit

**Weapons**
    Explosive Charge

 **Parts**
    Wood Pillar
    Wood Foundation
    Wood Wall
    Wood Doorway
    Metal Pillar
    Metal Foundation
    Metal Wall
    Metal Doorway
    Metal Stairs
```

This is taken from the rust wiki : http://playrustwiki.com/wiki/Airdrops

---

**edit**

I just noticed the scale of this question. Allow me to further add information to my answer.

There are three different kinds of chests found in the world.

**[Red crates](http://playrustwiki.com/wiki/Red_Crate)**

```
In red crates you can find the following items:
Medical Equipment
Blueprints
Flare
9mm Ammo
Shotgun Shells
556 Ammo
Loot Sacks
Anti-Radiation Pills
Explosive Charge
```

**[Yellow crates](http://playrustwiki.com/wiki/Yellow_Crate)**

```
Yellow Crates may contain the following items:
Ammunition
Weapon Attachments
Blueprints
Weapons
```

**[Green crates](http://playrustwiki.com/wiki/Green_Crate)**

```
Green Crates may contain the following items:
Weapons
Weapon Attachments
Ammunition
Paper
Research Kit 1
Blood Draw Kit
```

There are also the wooden boxes found everywhere (although these commonly contain the least valuable loot there is a rare chance of something of actual value being in there).

**Wooden boxes**

```
**Ammunition**
9mm Ammo
Shotgun Shells
556 Ammo

**Resources**
Cloth
Metal Fragments

**Medical Equipment**
Anti-Radiation Pills

**Consumables**
Can of Beans
Granola Bar
Small Water Bottle
```

The chance of each item spawning is not mentioned in the wiki so that should need some more research.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that you can't find, at the moment I write, in crates/red animals are Supply Signals. It has been added a couple of week/patch ago a very small probability (less than 1%) to drop C4 from animals.

Answer (score 0):

I got both of the supplies and this it what I found:
300   Blackpowder
50    wooden planks
4     explosives
5     hand granate
1     explosive charge
100   shotgun shells
250   9mm rounds
250   of the last ammunition typ (hunting like)
200   metal fragments
10    big med-packs

Might have been some flares and other stuff too that I've forgotten, but I think this was the main content in the TWO supplies :)

Comment: There are three crate drops, not two.  Also, their contents are randomized...

Answer (score 0):

- Explosives
- Supply Signal

That's it

*edit: this information is no longer accurate*

Comment: source​​​​​​​​?

Comment: 200 hours of playtime :)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Metal parts and Low Quality Metal can be dropped from air crates but not found in normal crates.

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is either incorrect, incomplete or outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Once I had the whole plane to my self:

I got 3x the following loot:

- 50 wooden planks
- 200 gunpowder
- 200 metal fragments
- 5 explosives
- 5 large medkit
- 200 something else i forgot

One time I found only house building supplies.

But except for supply signal and explosives all can be found in game.